# Manifest issue app stopping

Tags: xml, android-studio, manifest

After that, I have changed my package name ( i tried the app earlier before changing it was working as a charm ) the app works fine but when I plan the call timer and it gets time to receive the call it says: the application has stopped and it closes.
and here is what it shows in my android studio

[image]

and here is my Manifest :

[image]

thank you!

Comment: Welcome idhmrm, to help you attract answers, I'd suggest revising your question according to these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try Invalid cached/Restart it might help